# When not more nested lists hide an element

Tags: jquery

I thought this was going to be an easy question to find in Stack Overflow but It looks I can't find the right answer.

I have a dynamic big nested list looking like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        category
        <span>+</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                sub-category
                <span>+</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        sub-category2
                        <span>+</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        sub-category2
                        <span>+</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                sub-category
                <span>+</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        category
        <span>+</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                sub-category
                <span>+</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                sub-category
                <span>+</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        category
        <span>+</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This dynamic list may have many nested list up to infinite sub-categories (if the client crazy enough to create them). Each `li` has a `span` which it will be the button to toggle the nested list inside.

I just want a simple (I thought) script where if a `li` does not have any `ul` inside, It will hide the `span`

My closest try was this one:

```
if ($("ul li:not(:has(ul))")) {
    $(this).find('.desplegar-categoria').hide();
}
```

But I can't make it work somehow. Quite sure I am missing something obvious and I will feel like an idiot after the answers, but I would really appreciate if you can put me out of this miserable state I'm at this moment.

Comment: Try `$("ul li:not(:has(ul))").each(function () { $(this).find('.desplegar-categoria').hide(); }`

Comment: jQuery objects are never "falsy" since they are always objects with properties. You *could* use `.length`, but it sounds like you want to hide all of the ones that don't have child `ul`s, not just the first one.

Comment: Correct. I dont' want a "show" buttom when there's nothing to show.

Comment: How is the HTML generated? Could you not omit the span when you create the HTML?

Comment: I can't because the clients can generate as many nested lvl's as they want. Programmers though it was easier to hide the buttom clients side. Will try your answer below now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track; just needed to iterate, not just a single `if`. So, instead of using a condition, let jQuery filter the list of elements based on your selector, then iterate using `each`, and hide the `span`s.

```js
$("ul li:not(:has(ul))").each(function() {
  $(this).find('span').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    category
    <span>+</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        sub-category
        <span>+</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            sub-category2
            <span>+</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            sub-category2
            <span>+</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        sub-category
        <span>+</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    category
    <span>+</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        sub-category
        <span>+</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        sub-category
        <span>+</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    category
    <span>+</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew I was close... but couple hours lost. Ty